# Converting single linked list to Binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Can we convert single linked list to binary tree?

In a singly linked list, we cannot traverse from left to right side of the tree as we can't traverse backwards.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DSA: Digital Signature Algorithm.

Comment: What does make a procedure a *conversion*, and not some other processing?

Comment: Yes, you can create a binary tree from a singly linked list. Just name all the links `right` and regard the head node as the root. Done. If this is not what you want, then make sure to mention all the constraints and requirements in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Possible way: find middle element in the list, make it a root and create left and right children from left part of the list and right part of the list recursively. To find middle, you can first scan list to know its length and then make half of steps from beginning (or use trick like hare and turtle pointers).

At every division you know lengths of parts, so it is not needed to calculate them again  `l_len = len/2; r_len = len - 1 - len/2`

Something like this pseudocode (have not tested, perhaps checks for null are needed somewhere)

Length of the list:

```
GetLen(List):
   P = List.Start
   L = 0
   while P
      L++
      P = P.Next
   return L
```

Make balanced binary tree:

```
MakeTree(Node, L)
   P = Node
   L/2 - 1 steps:
      P = P.Next 
   Mid = P.Next
   RightNode = P.Next.Next  
   P.Next = null
   Mid.Left = MakeTree(Node, L/2)
   Mid.Right = MakeTree(RightNode, L - L/2 - 1) 
   return Mid   

 A-B-C-D-E-0
 L = 5
 5/2-1 = 1 steps move to B, next node (C) is mid

 A-B - C - D-E-0
       ^
       |
       mid(C)
     /       \
    A-B-0     D-E-0
```

Next recursion calls make:

```
         C
        / \
       /   \
      B     E
     / \   / \
    A  0   D  0
```

Comment: how we can link to last node of left list to first element of right list